# @ngboostrap Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript. when using webpack

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to get bootstrap 4 working with webpack and angular 2. From what I've read the best way to do this is to use ng-bootstrap.

I've added '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap', to my vendor list after jquery per the instructions and put in the imports in my app.module.ts file.

However when I run the app I get a ZoneSymbolError when I run it in the browser.

I've ensured my webpack.config.vendor.js has been rebuilt etc. and moving things around causes slightly different errors but none of them work properly.

Is there any example (I couldn't find one) or suggestions on how to get ng-bootstrap working with webpack?

Edit: Here's the webpack vendor area.

```
entry: {
        vendor: [
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/compiler',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/router',
            '@angular/platform-server',
            'angular2-universal',
            'angular2-universal-polyfills',
            'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap',
            'es6-shim',
            'es6-promise',
            'event-source-polyfill',                
            'zone.js',
        ]
    },
```

And here's the error:

Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript. at m (http://localhost:5000/dist/vendor.js?v=kFPeLwtbBxRH90pdzruTblX-UHexGi3YXcDeNvhxzsw:1061:2209) at Object. (http://localhost:5000/dist/main-client.js?v=RLXNCyPanqpzRmxUCWX-fr4myBJMfSl5_2XrNSlvG-E:1700:9) at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:5000/dist/main-client.js?v=RLXNCyPanqpzRmxUCWX-fr4myBJMfSl5_2XrNSlvG-E:660:30) at fn (http://localhost:5000/dist/main-client.js?v=RLXNCyPanqpzRmxUCWX-fr4myBJMfSl5_2XrNSlvG-E:84:20) at Object.options.path (http://localhost:5000/dist/main-client.js?v=RLXNCyPanqpzRmxUCWX-fr4myBJMfSl5_2XrNSlvG-E:993:1) at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:5000/dist/main-client.js?v=RLXNCyPanqpzRmxUCWX-fr4myBJMfSl5_2XrNSlvG-E:660:30) at fn (http://localhost:5000/dist/main-client.js?v=RLXNCyPanqpzRmxUCWX-fr4myBJMfSl5_2XrNSlvG-E:84:20) at Object. (http://localhost:5000/dist/main-client.js?v=RLXNCyPanqpzRmxUCWX-fr4myBJMfSl5_2XrNSlvG-E:6108:18) at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:5000/dist/main-client.js?v=RLXNCyPanqpzRmxUCWX-fr4myBJMfSl5_2XrNSlvG-E:660:30) at module.exports (http://localhost:5000/dist/main-client.js?v=RLXNCyPanqpzRmxUCWX-fr4myBJMfSl5_2XrNSlvG-E:709:38) at http://localhost:5000/dist/main-client.js?v=RLXNCyPanqpzRmxUCWX-fr4myBJMfSl5_2XrNSlvG-E:712:10

If I put jquery back in it says that jquery must be loaded before but it is and it still errors.

Comment: ng-bootstrap does **not** require jQuery. If you don't show the relevant code, config and error, there's not much we can do.

Comment: Then why does the error come up at all? Am I able to just remove jquery completely now with bootstrap 4 and ngbootstrap? Is there any documentation on how to add this stuff to webpack?

Comment: Update: Removing jquery completely does not help

Comment: @JBNizet I've added the code and the error. Putting back jquery doesn't matter no matter the order either.

Comment: Are you using the ASP.NET Core template? I fixed the issue by removing this line `import 'bootstrap';` from the boot-client.ts file

Comment: That's it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing by the looks of your error you're using the ASP.NET Core/Angular template. To fix it I had to remove the following line from the boot-client.ts file.

`import 'bootstrap';`

Comment: It did fix the problem but can you please explain why?

Comment: I'm honestly not even sure why that line is there. Removing it clearly isn't an issue. Since it's somehow picking up bootstrap from node-modules, importing it right at the start like that is just triggering another error within Bootstrap to require jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

To use widgets from [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) you do *not* need jQuery and do *not* need Bootstrap's JavaScript. The only required dependency is on Bootstrap's CSS.

You are getting the error on your side since, most probably, you are including Bootstrap's JavaScript. Once again, this is not needed - the only dependency is on CSS.

You might want to have a look at the ng-bootstrap demo site that uses WebPack - if you inspect [its vendor file](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/24e86e60fd908e0e642dca0298b2034ace593fcf/demo/src/vendor.ts) you will notice that only Bootstrap's CSS is referenced:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Comment: Bootstrap has been removed from the webpack config entirely. Only ng-bootstrap exists and the .css file. That's it. This is webpack specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can include `jQuery` by using the following steps:

1. Install `jQuery` using `npm`

   `npm install jquery -- save`
2. go to the `angular.json` OR `angular-cli.json` file at the root of your project folder and add below code in your `scripts` tag

   `"scripts": [ 
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
   ]`

make sure you entered correct path.

3. Stop Angular CLI application and re-run is using `ng-serve` command.
4. Now, when you use `jQuery` to any component then import it as below code:

   `import * as $ from 'jquery';`