# Installing bootstrap@4.0.0-beta on ASP.NET Core Angular template

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, asp.net-core

After installing bootstrap@4.0.0-beta I found the follow error in the browsers console log

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be
>   included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.

I removed `import 'bootstrap';` from my boot.browser.ts after reading the answer to this question

[@ngboostrap Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript. when using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587290/ngboostrap-bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery-jquery-must-be-included-befo)

which solved my issue, although whenever I try using the following code in my app.component.html from the [bootstrap starter template](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/starter-template/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

It will not render any of the styling.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your _Layout.cshtml via a Gist?